# Css distribute number of elements evenly in 2 columns

Tags: html, css

I've content in the li's below that can be expended via an accordion on click:

```
<ul>
<li>Accordion item 1</li>
<li>Accordion item 2</li>
<li>Accordion item 3</li>
<li>Accordion item 4</li>
<li>Accordion item 5</li>
</ul>
```

With this css

```
ul {
columns: 2;
}
li {
break-inside: avoid;
}
```

If all items are collapsed, the columns: 2 works just fine.

However, as soon as an item is expended to take more height, the items get distributed unevenly.

What I'd like is for the number of elements (li's in this case) to be the same on either side at all times when collapsed or expanded.

I'll try to illustrate:

```
Collapsed:
Accordion item 1 | Accordion item 4
Accordion item 2 | Accordion item 5
Accordion item 3 |

Item 1 expanded:
Accordion item 1 Expanded | Accordion item 3
Accordion item 1 Expanded | Accordion item 4
Accordion item 1 Expanded | Accordion item 5
Accordion item 2          |

I cannot have the elements re-ordered, it should be:
Accordion item 1 Expanded | Accordion item 4
Accordion item 1 Expanded | Accordion item 5
Accordion item 1 Expanded |
Accordion item 2          |
Accordion item 3          |
```

Is there a trick to achieve this?

Comment: Consider to put all `Accordion item 1 Expanded` in a single `li`, not separate ones

Comment: They are in a single li whether expanded or collapsed. My illustration isn't the most obvious sorry.